# Taking ownership of file/folder in Windows

Tags: windows, permissions

Is there any situation when an account with administrator privileges isn't enough to perform certain action and it's then necessary to take ownership of a file or folder in Windows? If there is, I don't understand what's the point. As I have admin privileges, then I can change the ownership of this file/folder to whatever I want and thus perform intended actions.

Comment: Being logged in as an account with admin privileges is not the same as being logged in as Administrator - but aside from that, I don't really grok the logic behind it

Comment: The difference is all about the fact that THE Admin account already has the elevated privileges? Normal user with admin privileges has to deal with UAC. Or there is something more?

Comment: I'd say knock down UAC a bit - but I'm not sure this forum would support that view so I held off in my first response.